# Why toString does not allow throws clause

Tags: java

I am trying to add `throws` clause to a `toString` method but the compiler says:

> Exception IllegalAccessException is not compatible with throws clause in Object.toString()

Here is my code:

```
public class NF {

    private final Long id;
    private final String name;

    public static class Builder {
        private Long id = null;
        private String name = null;

        // setters of id and name

        public NF build() {
            return new NF(this);
        }
    }

    public NF(Builder b) {
        this.id = b.id;
        this.name = b.name;
    }

    public String toString() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        String toString = "";
        for (Field f : fields) {
            String name = f.getName();
            Object value = f.get(this); // throws checked exceptions
            if (value != null)
                toString += name.toUpperCase() + ": " + value.toString() + "%n";
        }
        return String.format(toString);
    }

}
```

Why can't I add `throws` to `toString`?

Comment: Simply because the `Object` method doesn't throw one. Imagine that you have `Object o = new NF();`. How the compiler should know that `o.toString()` could throw an exception since the method declared doesn't ?

Comment: Adding a checked exception to an overridden method breaks its contract.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `toString()` is rather a debugging aid to provide a way to quickly inspect an object's content. As such, it should not change program flow in any significant way, which is the reason why it must not throw.

Comment: You can't add new checked exception when you are overriding method. Lets say we have `Parent p = new Child();`. If we could add new exceptions to lets say `someMethod` then when invoking `p.someMethod()` compiler will make us catch and handle *only* exceptions declared in Parent class to be thrown, but this way we can skip potential exceptions added in Child class so it would be big security flaw.

Comment: Overridden methods can throw Exceptions, so long as the method being overridden also throws the same Exceptions. You can't introduce new Exceptions. This is based on Liskov substitution principle (see-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you override a method, you can't throw checked exceptions that are not sub-classes of exceptions that already appear in the `throws` clause of the overridden method. Otherwise you break the contract of the overridden method.

Since `Object`'s `toString` doesn't throw any checked exceptions, any class that overrides `toString()` can't throw checked exceptions in that method. You must catch these exceptions internally.

Note that `IllegalArgumentException` is a `RuntimeException` exception, so you can still throw it (you don't have to specify it in a `throws` clause).

On the other hand, `IllegalAccessException` is a checked exception, so you must handle it internally.

```
public String toString() {
    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    String toString = "";
    for (Field f : fields) {
        try {
            String name = f.getName();
            Object value = f.get(this);
            if (value != null)
                toString += name.toUpperCase() + ": " + value.toString() + "%n";
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            // either ignore the exception, or add something to the output
            // String to indicate an exception was caught
        }
    }
    return String.format(toString);
}
```